# Do I use random randint or random choice to random click on the list?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, random

[image][image]

For the picture below, I wish to perform an automation testing which is random click on the items and save it. Is this consider as a list?

**Selenium Python**

Comment: random.choice would be better since it self-documents the code more, but random.randint would work as well

Comment: Do It allow me to select different number of lists for every testing? @AlexanderSoiefer

Comment: You don't have that many choices... I would just loop through them all to make sure they are all covered. Doing a random choice and running that script daily may take a while before you actually test a UI choice that has an issue.

Comment: It should, if the size of the container list is changed as well. @Carl Carl. Also, unless you plan on scaling the code (or it needs to be using this method for a class project), I would recommend using JeffC's method.

Comment: I dont get u, @AlexanderSoiefer, what u mean is recommend me to random select one of the lists and loop through them?

Comment: @CarlCarl I mean to loop through the list consisting of all the lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the one that suits the format you have the elements in. If you have a list of the elements themselves, `random.choice` is the better option; if you only have the number of elements, you might prefer `random.randint`.

Comment: Hi bro, I've uploaded a new picture, could u help me to c if it consider as a list of the elements? 
@Rahul